# What word do we use for necessary but unspecified stuff?

Tags: word-choice, word-request, word-in-context

Here's the question

> where did you go on the holiday?
>
> Nowhere. I stayed home and did some overdue job/task/work/....

Overdue is not necessary here, other words may fit.
I want to talk about unspecified things like doing some cleaning and doing my homework and so on.

Another example:

> What do you want to do on the weekend?
>
> I'm going to stay home and........

Answer (score 4):

The phrase you may be looking for might begin with "***catching up on***" and then include

> **work** around the house
>   **chores** around the house
>   **odd jobs** around the house
>   **odd tasks** around the house

and the always unspecified

> **stuff**

So you might have

> I'm going to stay home and **catch up on work around the house**.
>   I'm going to stay home and **catch up on chores around the house**.
>   I'm going to stay home and **catch up on odd jobs around the house**.
>   I'm going to stay home and **catch up on odd tasks around the house**.
>   I'm going to stay home and **catch up on stuff**.

Comment: Great answer. Can I use this verb phrase with class assignments and homework as well?

Comment: @MasihK Yes, you can. You can "catch up" on any task that you feel you are behind on.